# Generating preview images for DOC, TXT and RTF files

Tags: php, image-processing

I've been trying to find a method of achieving this for awhile now with no luck.

Unfortunately none of these formats are supported by ImageMagicK

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Customize the code to fit into your requirements.

I've attached a sample image generated from a text file that contains "Generating preview images for TXT files" sentence by the following code:

```
<?php
Header ("Content-type: image/gif");
$txtfile = "test.txt";
$testarr = array();
if(!file_exists($txtfile)){
$string = "File not found.";
}
else{
$testarr = file($txtfile);
srand ((float) microtime() * 10000000);
$string = '-'.$testarr[array_rand($testarr)];
$string = substr($string,0,strlen($string)-2);
}
$font = 4;
$width = ImageFontWidth($font)* strlen($string);
$height = ImageFontHeight($font);
$im = ImageCreate($width,$height);
$x=imagesx($im)-$width ;
$y=imagesy($im)-$height;
$background_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 242, 242, 242); //  white colored background
$text_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0,0);  //  black colored text 
$trans_color = $background_color;           //  transparent 
imagecolortransparent($im, $trans_color);
imagestring ($im, $font, $x, $y, $string, $text_color);
imagegif($im);
ImageDestroy($im);
?>
```

[image]

Links would be useful :

http://visionmasterdesigns.com/tutorial-convert-text-into-transparent-png-image-using-php/

http://www.phpro.org/examples/Text-to-Image-with-GD.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to need to do this on a machine with a GUI/Window environment by opening the files and then taking screenshots of them like http://litmus.com/ or https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html

There is a program written do this for PDFs from HTML using WebKits rendering engine: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to convert all those documents to pdf and then print that pdf to image.

For Doc to PDF, you could try [LiveDocx](http://www.phplivedocx.org/).