# How do you make a document viewer for a device?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, device, document

I need to make a document (doc, pdf) viewer for a device(ipad,iphone,etc, doesn't matter). The user uploads a document file and wants to see it on his device. I'm working with php, code igniter, though it doesn't matter much.

What's the best way to do this?

All I could come up with is turning the document into an image (like so [Generating preview images for DOC, TXT and RTF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171863/generating-preview-images-for-doc-txt-and-rtf-files)) and just throwing the image on the device for the user to see.

Is there a simpler/more efficient/other way? Am I missing something, like a magic parser?

Thanks.

Comment: "for a device" - now you could be way more specific than that.

Comment: Crisitan Prodan not even close. One doesn't/can't utilize the same code/APIs/whatever for a mobile phone, a microcontroller-based board, a desktop computer, etc...

Comment: Dude it doesn't matter, I'm 'converting' my code when I make the build with phonegap. I just want to know if I should use the image solution or parse the file somehow.

Comment: plus almost any language can display html code or images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options regarding PDF's:

- Converting a PDF to swf : http://www.swftools.org/pdf2swf.html
- Embeding using scribd API: http://www.scribd.com/developers
- Converting the PDF to HTML : http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/

Now, regarding the word doc...it gets harder. The way I would approach it would be to either use [www.phpdocx.com](http://www.phpdocx.com)(I think you'd need atleast the Pro+ Version) / [www.phplivedocx.org](http://www.phplivedocx.org)(this one works as a service), or, if running a windows server is an option, to have word installed on the server and use [COM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) to convert the document as you need( it can be saved as xml or html - or even a pdf).

AFAIK there is no single unified wrapper or library that can handle it.

edit: Theres also the option of using OpenOffice to convert the word document(which is free and runs on linux)

Comment: seems they closed my question, anyway thanks for the help man